# Vertical half page background image (in Squarespace)

Tags: css, image, background, squarespace

I'm looking to achieve a half page background image that looks like this: www.washiarts.com. I used Squarespace to build the site as I'm new to web design... please be kind.

I understand I need to use a container and then have the image within that, though I'm struggling to do it in Squarespace using the options for code inputs. I can place the image and align it properly using variations on this code, but it appears stretched:

```
> body {
   background-image: url("IMAGE URL");
   background-position: 0;
   background-size: 50% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Read this, it'll help! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's hard not to make it stretch. Washiarts.com's bg-image is also slightly stretching. They use `background-size: cover;`

How about making a repeatable pattern and make it repeat downwards?

```
body {
   background-image: url("http://i285.photobucket.com/albums/ll53/ellee2012/Cute/0-75.png~original");
   background-size: 50%;
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! That is almost perfect - it just repeats slightly at the bottom. I was hoping to use one big image rather than a pattern (sorry I didn't specify that). Is there anyway to just omit the slight repetition?

Comment: I edited my original image and it's removed the repeat. I'd still love to know how to add it into a container but I have a viable solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want it to repeat just use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` But be aware of that the image will be too small for others who have a higher screen resolution than your.

Comment: A solution could be that you edit your image and make 50% of it transparent. Then you use the `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: 100% 100%;` to fill out the screen. The last solution will properly stretch your image.